# How to embed an interactive terminal in a python GUI and intercept what's typed in?

Tags: python, shell

I'm developing a python application and at some point I would like to open an interactive shell terminal (like bash or xterm) for the user. I also need to read and modify the commands typed in this terminal before their execution.

I have a python with a GUI created from tkinter widgets.

I read about the Cmd module for python and it's default method but it does not allow to autocomplete shell commands (only the one added). Also it does not seem possible to keep the terminal state (current directory etc.)

I have read some stuff about embedding xterm with the `-into` option in my app. It's nearly what I need but it does not allow me to modify the commands typed in before they are launched.

I basically need something like the software faraday has done:
[image: expected]

Typed in commands are read and completed on the fly with elements depending on what command was going to be launched.

Thanks